# Alternative to Switch Case Reading XML

Tags: c#, xml, switch-statement

The below function locates a file, navigates to the specified parent nodes, and goes through the child nodes looking for predefined element names.

I am reading from an XML file and assigning the node inner text values to static fields and only wish to pick out certain nodes, these may not necessarily be in order as users will be allowed to edit the XML config file.

At present I have had to hard code in the order of the nodes' appearances unsure what's wrong with the switch case as I didn't think this mattered - ideally I wish to avoid this.

Is there a better alternative to this or is there something I'm doing wrong with the switch case?

My code as it stands:

```
        public void ReadConfig()
    {
        string fp = _AppPath + @"\myfolder";
        try
        {
            string confPath = (fp + @"\config.xml");
            XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xDoc.Load(configfilepath);
            XmlNode xmlLst = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("parentnode/childnode");

            foreach (XmlNode node in xmlLst.ChildNodes)
            {
                switch(node.Name)
                {
                    case "user":
                        _User = node.InnerText;
                        break;
                    case "password":
                        _Password = node.InnerText;
                        break;
                    case "serverip":
                        _serverIP = node.InnerText;
                        break;
                    case "mailport":
                        _mailPort = int.Parse(node.InnerText);
                        break;
                    case "recipient":
                        _recipient = node.InnerText;
                        break;
                    default:
                        WriteErrorLog("Issue getting server details from XML config file.");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

**Fully working Solution**

Thanks for assistance, below is the working code.

```
        public static void ReadFromXMLXDoc()
    {
        // XDocument xDocu;
        string xmlFilePath = (@"somewhere\Config.xml");
        XDocument xDocu = XDocument.Load(xmlFilePath);
        XElement xmlList = xDocu.Element("configuration").Element("parent").Element("child");
        _one = (string)xmlList.Element("option1");
        _two = (string)xmlList.Element("option2");
        _three = (string)xmlList.Element("option3");
        Console.WriteLine(_one + " " + _two + " " + _three);
        Console.ReadLine();          
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As alternative to your current approach, you can use multiple `SelectSingleNode()`s like so :

```
XmlNode xmlLst = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("parentnode/childnode");
_User = xmlLst.SelectSingleNode("user").InnerText;
_Password = xmlLst.SelectSingleNode("password").InnerText;
....
```

or you can try an entirely different route using newer XML API, `XDocument`, instead of `XmlDocument` :

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(configfilepath);
Xelement xmlLst = xDoc.Element("parentnode").Element("childnode");
_User = (string)xmlLst.Element("user");
_Password = (string)xmlLst.Element("password");
....
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to XDocument, much simpler, like it!

Answer (score 0):

And another alternative approach is use `Dictionary<string, string>`, something like this :

```
string confPath = (fp + @"\config.xml");
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load(configfilepath);
XmlNode xmlLst = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("parentnode/childnode");
var nodeDict = xmlLst.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlNode>()
               .ToDictionary(nodeKey => nodeKey.Name, nodeVal => nodeVal.InnerText);
```

and now its time to access the value.

```
var _User = nodeDict["user"];
// OR
Console.WriteLine(nodeDict["user"] + " " + nodeDict["password"] + " " + nodeDict["serverip"]);
//...... so on........
```